# MS Visual Studio existing saved sql files cannot access saved database connection from server explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I am new to Visual Studio, but I am very familiar with many different development IDEs.

I am using MS Visual Studio Community Edition 2019, and I have a hosted website with a Ms SQL Server 2016 database.

I've connected to the database successfully within Visual Studio and saved the connection in the Server Explorer as a database connection.
It tests successfully, and I am able to launch a query from the server explorer entry for that connection and select/update/insert etc without problem.

When I open an existing saved SQL file, it does not allow the option to connect to my saved connection in the server explorer. The options under both History and Browse, local/network/Azure....  nothing shows my saved database connection.

Is there something I am not aware of, or that I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

- Flynn

Answer (score 0):

Once you open a `.sql` script in Visual Studio; right click in the editor where you see the SQL code, and go to *Connection* and then use **Connect** or **Change Connection** to change where you are connected/connecting to.

[image: connection menu]

Comment: Thank for explaining HOW to connect it.

Comment: BUT....  I was asking how to connect it to an EXISTING DATABASE CONNECTION within Visual Studio.

Comment: @Flynn what do you mean by a existing database connection? Do you not know the server name and database name to plug in?

Comment: For clarity....  When I follow those steps you offer, vvvv4d, I cannot use the existing database connection *already* in the solution explorer.

Comment: I'm saying, I would expect the database connection already established in Visual Studio to be useable by SQL.  And so far, it is not.  Why should it do this?  Because SQL Server Management Studio has the functionality.  Makes no sense that MS would not use the same functionality within Visual Studio if they're including database connectivity.

Comment: No I am not.  It is an ASP.NET Core app. project.

Comment: Visual Studio and SSMS are similar but don't have exact feature parody. There is a lot SSMS can do that Visual Studio cannot. Such as Importing Files, and also being intelligent when you connect to a server in object explorer if you open a file or new query window SSMS knows to use the connection from the object explorer.

Comment: As a career developer, I am utterly amazed that Visual Studio overlooked such basic functionality.  Wow.

Comment: Thank you, vvvv4d, I appreciate the hand holding :)

Comment: If your working with `.sql` files SSMS is a more appropriate tool to use than Visual Studio. Visual Studio can work but, it has some downfalls and limitations SSMS doesn't have like what you've run into.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220157/discussion-between-flynn-and-vvvv4d).